# Set the current directory when running a SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python

Is there any way to set the directory where you want to start a SimpleHTTPServer or BaseHTTPServer?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you're using `SimpleHTTPServer` directly from command line, you can simply use shell features:

```
pushd /path/you/want/to/serve; python -m SimpleHTTPServer; popd
```

In Python 3 you have to use:

```
pushd /path/you/want/to/serve; python -m http.server; popd
```

> The SimpleHTTPServer module has been merged into http.server in Python 3.0

Comment: No, I'm using it from inside an application.

Comment: @Ubersoldat: Then answer's the same: Use the shell to set the current working directory.  Or use `os.setcwd()` -- it's the same thing.

Comment: @S.Lott os.setcwd doesn't exist, but os.chdir(path) does the job. Thanks to both.

Comment: @Ubersoldat: Apologies -- I did that from memory.  Wish I could edit the comment.

Comment: @Eldelshell put that comment into an answer.

Comment: The popd gets never executed because SimpleHTTPServer never returns.

Comment: `os.chdir()` if you are facing 'AttributeError' for `os.setcwd` like me.

Answer (score 3):

If instead of command line you need to run it from your code, `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` receive a `directory` argument that its default value is current directory:

```
def __init__(self, *args, directory=None, **kwargs):
    if directory is None:
        directory = os.getcwd()
```

You can use it like this:

```
import http.server

class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, directory='/path/to/your/dir')

def main():
    http.server.test(Handler)  # test(Handler, port=8080)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you don't want to serve any index, you can set the `directory` arg to `/dev/null` on Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it **without** changing directory on Linux:

```
bash -c "cd /your/path; python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script for this (say `microserver.sh`), and put this inside

```
#!/bin/bash

pushd /your/directory/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &> /dev/null &
popd
```

Then, change the permissions:

```
chmod +x microserver.sh
```

And execute it:

```
./microserver.sh
```

This will avoid printing messages to the console and send the process to the background, so you can continue using the console for other things.

Also, it could be called from other scripts, e.g. it can be added to the `~/.bashrc` to start the server upon starting the user session. Just add this at the end of the `.bashrc`

```
. ./microserver.sh
```