# python -m SimpleHTTPServer - Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000 but http://0.0.0.0:8000/test.html gives "Page Not Found"

Tags: python, macos, terminal, webserver

After cding to my folder I enter

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and get

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

in reply. But when I hit `http://0.0.0.0:8000/test.html` I get a page not found error.

I've also tried

```
pushd /path/you/want/to/serve; python -m SimpleHTTPServer; popd
```

taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469256/set-the-current-directory-when-running-a-simplehttpserver)

When I hit ls I can see the file and the directory. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think the other two answers are trying to make it clear that 0.0.0.0 is not the URL you should be visiting. When a Python web server (like cherrypy for instance) says it is serving on 0.0.0.0 it means it is listening for all TCP traffic that ends up at that machine no matter the hostname or IP that was requested. But, if you change it such that the socket listens on 127.0.0.1 or 'localhost', then unless the request was specifically to that IP/hostname, it won't respond to the request. For example, many times you can use your machine name instead of localhost (ubuntu allows this for example). If your machine name is 'brian' and you have a server listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, you should be able to reach that server with http://brian:8080. But if that server is listening on 'localhost', even though 'brian' is set to point to 'localhost', the server won't receive the message.

You also need to be sure the file really is in the directory you are running the command from. Otherwise, the 404 response is actually correct :)

Good luck!

Comment: http://COMPUTERNAME.local:8000/ works perfectly! Thanks. COMPUTERNAME is found in System Preferences > Sharing

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ?

:)

Comment: Have now and thats not it. The thing is that 0.0.0.0:8000/ is showing a custom 'Page Not Found' message.

Comment: In that case, make sure you have no other web servers running at localhost.

Comment: For explanation : IP adress 0.0.0.0 will open your web server on local network. It's not a valid IP for an host. Your host stay accessible from 127.0.0.1 (or with local network IP).

Answer (score 4):

You must type in the ip-address of the computer your connecting to for example 192.168.0.2:8000 Change that to the ip-address of your server.

Answer (score 2):

Try browsing to http://localhost:8000/test.html or http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.html (those two should be exactly the same thing as long as your hosts file isn't all crazy-like).

0.0.0.0 is usually used by Windows as the "Not connected" IP, and can also be used as a sort of wildcard for when dealing with IPs. I am a bit confused at why your HTTP server is trying to host on 0.0.0.0, though. You may need to edit some config files and set that to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means listen on all interfaces

Answer (score 2):

Try to host over localhost may it help you instead of trying it on `http://0.0.0.0/` like this way: `python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

1. create a directory e.g. `mkdir HTTPServer_dir`
2. move inside the folder `cd HTTPServer_dir`
3. typing the command (according to python version) `python -m SimpleHTTPSever 8000`
   (or the port you want)
4. go on a browser and type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Done !!!

You could make a simple index.html page inside the HTTPServer_dir so you can see an html page instead of directory listing

Answer (score 0):

Run `ifconfig` on Linux or `ipconfig` on Windows to find the ip address of the server.

```
$ sudo ifconfig
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:3a:64:b3:be:6a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Here in case the url would be:

http://192.168.1.103:8000/test.html

Answer (score 0):

try this in python3

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

and in your browser this url:

> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the same port number is used by some other service. So we can try with some other port like

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9090
```

And then simply hit http://{your system IP}:9090/

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me,replacing your machine name with
    http://localhost:x000

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 8. Did not download any software!

In cmd:

1. Go to the directory that your file is in.
2. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
   Shows "Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ..."

Now, find out your system name. For Windows 8: Control Panel -> System. You will see the computer name here. Let's say it is "Abhinav".

Your local server will be hosted at "Abhinav.local:8000".